# Login from an identity provider without accessing the login form

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am using Keycloak Identity Server for SSO.

I created an Identity Provider (WSO2) and it works fine with Keycloak Identity Server.

But after I have logged on website A (using WSO2) and switch to website B (using Keycloak). I need to click the login with Identity Provider button.

Is there a way to automatically bypass login website B from if I logged on website A? (just redirect to website B and dont need to do any other action)

Thanks in advance ^^.

Comment: I am not sure but I thing that you can do something related with store token during the configuration of the IDP

Comment: I tried this but it still doesn't change

Comment: Okey, but how would KC know about that you are login into the website A ? If you are login into SO using gmail.com it does not mean that when you login into gmail.com that you will be automatically login into SO.

Comment: Do you have multiple identity providers configured with Keycloak or just WSO2? And do you have non-federated user in addition?

Comment: You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51504099/16357334) by @bmaupin

Comment: @sventorben I have only one identity provider WSO2. And I configured create new user in keycloak after first login from WSO2