# Use Keycloak's SAML redirection without going through the login screen

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, saml

I have a Keycloak server running, and I have set up some identity providers on it (some of them are SAML 2.0).
I also have a Quarkus project where I'm supposed to authenticate users with a nice login screen that is already done. My idea is the following:

- The user should enter their email address.

  - If this email address needs to be authenticated with a password I would request the user to introduce the password and authenticate it against Keycloak using OpenID Connect.
  - If this email address needs to be authenticated using SAML 2.0 I would redirect the user to their login screen.
    The problem arises in the second case. I need Keycloak to generate the SAML Auth Request for me (cause I don't want to use a SAML library in my Quarkus project), this is, to generate the SAML Auth Request that is generated when the user clicks the IDP Provider button in the original Keycloak login screen (that I don't want to use).

I tried to use the `kc_idp_hint` parameter of the auth request in OpenID Connect as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46390571/how-to-bypass-keycloak-login-form-and-jump-directly-to-the-idp-login). But the problem is that, as said [here](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/kc-idp-hint-for-saml-client/18197), you should have previously created the SAML Auth Request with another library (and I want Keycloak to do it).

Summarizing: Can I "emulate" the Keycloak's Identity Provider button to bypass the login screen?

Thanks!